# iOS: How to learn how much memory a process is using (by pid number)?

Tags: ios, memory, process

I want to find one how much memory a bunch of processes are using on the iPhone.

Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK iOS developer tools will not allow you to check 'other' process memory consumption. You can't ask the OS information about the entire system, but not specify processes. :(

You can, anyways, check that memory by using a Jailbroken device. I do it, using:

- **ssh access** (installing *openssh* first, off course) and using `top` or `ps aux`
- system information (from Cydia) [SystemInformation](http://modmyi.com/cydia/com.pear.systeminformation)

Maybe there is another tool, but I was unable to find (and **I tried**!) one that give you exact information of each running process.

ps: remember that iOs devices use a default root password as `alpine` and you **should** change it on your first access to avoid security risks.